# jQuery .change function triggers in Internet Explorer even though nothing on the screen is being changed

Tags: jquery

I have a screen that checks for changes to input fields (text, dropdown, etc). If changes are detected, the user is alerted, similar to the example below:

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but a couple of users on IE 11 are getting the alert even though nothing is changed. Other users on IE 11, and even older versions of IE are fine. I cannot replicate the scenario.

Comment: and if you use bind or on?

Comment: Maybe those people have some add-on? But I would remove the `alert`. It is an annoying thing anyway. Change it with a less intrusive, message next to the input.

Comment: I should clarify that it isn't an instant alert. I save the fact that something changed in a var, and then alert the user if they attempt to navigate away from the screen before saving their changes. It is the $(".target").change that is triggering every time, even though nothing on the screen is changed